# How does Hibernate's session.save proxy a transient object?

Tags: hibernate, proxy, persistent, transient

```java
 SomeClass transientObject = new SomeClass();//Transient POJO
 session.save(transientObject);
 transientObject.setSomeProperty("someValue");//This is a persistent object now
```

How does hibernate proxy the `transientObject` at runtime?

Or does it simply save a copy of `transientObject` in the `persistenceContext`, mapped to the object reference of `transientObject` and compare the objects while the transaction is committed?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate remembers the object reference and at transaction commit, it will check all objects in the persistence context if they are dirty. Dirty objects are then flushed to the database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes sense. Could you add a summary of the whole process or point to a reference that does? I still have questions like how Hibernate identifies the objects that are dirty? does it do a deep comparison? how does it store the object references? does the persistence context store a deep copy of the loaded persistent object?

Comment: When enhancement is enabled, objects do dirty tracking and Hibernate just queries that info for every object, otherwise it has to do a deep comparison. I don't know if there is a reference for this except the Hibernate code itself.